# What is this little fenced off area in Rustboro City for in ORAS?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Every time I go into route 115 from Rustboro City, there is a small opening in the fences that leads to a grass area that is 3x3.

What is it for?

Comment: Have you tried using your item finder there?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about this area, off to the side of Rustboro City:

[image: 3x3 Area off Rustboro]

Which in context is here:
[image: Rustboro City Map]
<sub>[Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rustboro_City)</sub>

There seems to be nothing special about the area.

- There are no hidden/visible items there
- It isn't part of the main story, nor the 'Delta Episode'
- There are no events/side quests that use the location
- It is not a secret base

It is either an oversight by the developers or simply a small design choice of the area.*

<sub>*Judging from the relatively small size, perhaps they couldn't fit another Tree sprite (like the ones surrounding it) in the spot.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no real reason for this, just part of the map.